# Javascript drag and drop functionality issue

Tags: javascript, html

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
  <head>
  <style>
  #div1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  }
  </style>
  <script>
  function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }

  function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  }

  function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <br>
  <img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">

  </body>
  </html>
```

Here is my code above.

I wants to drag one html element from one div to another with out removing the primary element.

When i am dragging element from one div to another it is going there but replacing the primary element. I wants my primary element should be stay steady on his own position after drop also.

Please have  a look and let me know there is any way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) primary element then add using

```
var cln = date.cloneNode(true);
```

```js
  function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }

  function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  }

  function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    let item = document.getElementById(data);
    var cln = item.cloneNode(true);
    ev.target.appendChild(cln);
  }
```

```css
  #div1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  }
```

```html
  <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <br>
  <img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
```

Comment: Thanks bro. It worked nicely. What is var cln = date.cloneNode(true);
 mean ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

Comment: The Node.cloneNode() method returns a duplicate of the node on which this method was called.

Comment: Added. Soory i forgot to do that.